# Unicode string extraction and comparison

Tags: regex, scala, unicode

```
1.val Matcher = """.+/(.*)""".r
2.val Matcher(title) = """http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Château_La_Louvière"""
3.val lowerCase = title.toLower
4.if(lowercase.equals("château_la_louvière")) //do something
```

The above comparison returns false because I guess line 2 results in Ch?teau_La_Louvi?re. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: For me your snippet works just fine. Check your locale settings. And also check, `sys.props("file.encoding")` should be `UTF-8`

Comment: That does not seem to work. I explicitly set the file encoding to UTF-8 still no luck.

Comment: I'm on mac with JDK7 and its working for me.

Comment: this is working for me as well - maybe becaus of mine scala 2.10

Answer (score 0):

As 4e6 says the problem lies within the standard configuration of Java. Which assumes all files encoded in Latin1.

```
1.val Matcher = """.+/(.*)""".r
2.val Matcher(title) = """http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Château_La_Louvière"""
```

This could be fixed by setting the following java-OPTS

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
```

Still 1. and 2. will work, even if you don't change the encoding. The Problem lies in 3. and 4. .

```
3.val lowerCase = title.toLower
4.if(lowercase.equals("château_la_louvière")) //do something
```

''toLower'' will cause the test in 4. to fail , because "â" and "è" will be interpreted wrongly. These characters would be encoded as two up to four bytes, which each will be lowercased independently thus yielding a completely different result as ''château_la_louvière'' .